# Setting a delay in a java program

Tags: java, delay

I'm sorry for such a newbie question, I'm trying to set a delay between two `JText` fields changing color i.e:

```
 box1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
 box2.setBackground(Color.red);
```

I've tried to use:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000); 
}catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

However when using this, the delay *happens instantly* and both colors only change after the delay. Thank you in advance for any light you shine on my situation :)

Comment: Where in the context of the code are you calling `Thread.sleep(1000)`? You have to call it in between the `setBackground()` calls, is that where you're calling it?

Comment: Yeah, when i call it inbetween the two colour changes, it ignores the first change, runs the delay and then calls both colour changes at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
box1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
new Thread(new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
       try{
          Thread.sleep(1000);
       }catch(InterruptedException ex){
          ex.printStackTrace();
       }
       box2.setBackground(Color.red);
   }
}).start();
```

If you execute Thread.sleep(1000); on main thread, the rendering of the page will be done once sleep is terminated and you will see both box changing their color.

If sleep runs in another thread different from main thread, mainThread rendering will be done immediately after the new thread is started and you can see the first box chaning his color. After the sleep is executed, box2 will change his color. Sorry for my english, i hope you can understand it :)

Comment: Thank you jack, this works perfectly, could you please explain what's happening in this code?